# Google service Ads behaves differently than AdMob SDK while loading ads?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I recently migrated my project from AdMob SDK to Google service Ads, however I got a tiny problem with the Google service Ads.

I have a banner ad view in the activity, and I would dynamically adjust the buttons in the layout depending on whether or not an ad is loaded. It worked fine when I used AdMob SDK, but now with Google service Ads, the banner is always reserved there with blank before the ad is loaded. And if the ad cannot be loaded (say without network), the blank view is there, which is rather ugly! This is also why I would like to adjust the layout dynamically...

Did I missed anything while I changed the code? Thank you for help!

Here is an excerpt of the java code and layout file:

Java:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
...
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
}
```

Layout XML:

```
...
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="AD_PUB_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In summary, how can I make an adView occupy no space before the ad is loaded with Google service Ads?

Comment: Can you put your .java class where you integrated the admob. and the manifest too.

Comment: @MohitRakhra, Thank you for the answer. I did the migration exactly as [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration) suggests. Anyway, I will post the file content in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an AdListener, and make the ad visible only when it receives an ad.

The code looks like this:

```
        final AdView ad = new AdView(context);
        ad.setAdUnitId(publisherId);
        ad.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        final AdListener listener = new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                ad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
        };

        ad.setAdListener(listener);
        ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        adParent.addView(ad);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Since there is/was an issue, that an AdMob ad generates an ANR, when it is destroyed when still loading. I normally also check on the visibility of the ad, before calling `pause()` or `destroy()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I guess I shall use it if I cannot figure out where goes wrong. Basically I think the code and layout are migrated to the Google service API equivalently to AdMob SDK, so I expect it would behave as before.

Comment: It is default behavior of the new api to always show the view. This has really changed, and is not the same as before.

Comment: Thank you again! It now clears my doubt, however can you please direct me to the Google site that describe such change? I appreciate that very much!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because this is against Google Ad policy to have the ad banner pops up like that.
I received a mail from Google a month ago and had to change that behavior to avoid my app to be banned from the Play Store.
A lot of developers are receiving the same mail.

Comment: I did not popup the ad banner indeed. What I was trying to do is that I decide the layout dynamically depending on the status of the ad loading. I hate the popup ad, which is annoying.

Comment: I know but the result is the same. The banner will popup (the banner will instantly appear if you prefer) at any time based on the success of the ad loading, but if the user is pressing controls near the banner position he can accidently press on the banner. Therefore Google now forces to reserve part of the screen to the ad banner, even when there's nothing to display

Comment: OK, that does make sense... But it really looks weird to leave some blank screen there...

Comment: What if a user has no internet connection? Then no das can be display, so in my opinion also the blank adview should be gone...

Comment: No the ad banner now works as a placeholder. It will display an empty space if there's nothing to show, and the ad otherwise